# Qual a diferença dos php.ini da pasta Apache2 e CLI?

Tags: php

Em minhas versões php, eu possuo essas duas pastas citadas(apache2 e CLI) e ambas contem o php.ini. Qual a diferença entre cada uma? Quando sei em qual posso ou devo alterar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um é especificamente para ser usado para o apache e outro para quando vai executar o php via terminal, o que não precisa ter nada a ver com web, por exemplo executar o `composer` ou executar `CRON` que chama scripts `.php`, seria terminal.

Isso é algo mais de como os repositórios de algumas distros trabalham, não é toda distro que vai seguir esse caminho.

A utilidade de ter arquivos `php.ini` separados é que para scripts `.php` voltados para terminal/cmd você poderá liberar recursos mais sensíveis, como permitir maior consumo de memória, algo que em um servidor web o ideal é limitar para evitar que scripts php "mal feitos" causem problemas inesperados.

Por exemplo se em terminal/cmd você sabe que não vai usar as extensões de banco de dados (através das [APIs PDO, mysqli, pgsql, etc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php)) então no php.ini especifico para CLI é quase certo que você poderá desabilita-las, **exceto** se você for chamar um script PHP externo via CRON ou via funções como `exec()`, `passthru()`, `shell_exec()`, `proc_open()` e `popen()` que precisem fazer alguma operação de banco de dados.

Vale lembrar que como eu disse, criar diferentes arquivos `php.ini` é algo praticamente customizável de cada distro (mais especificamente repositório), até você pode customizar por conta própria (dependendo da forma que o seu sistema operacional trabalha).

Comment: E quanto ao Web, onde são localizados a configuração de biblioteca? As bibliotecas são habilitadas pela linha 'extension' que tem dentro do php.ini para a Web também?

Comment: @Reginaldev não, você não precisará de todas extensões, vc pode desligar o extensão de mysql no site que usa postgres e desligar a extensão de postgres no site que usa mysql, a não ser que use migration), então geralmente poderá desligar todos módulos de banco nele.

Comment: ps: quando me refiro a módulo/extensão de banco, não estou falando dos bancos em si, pois geralmente os bancos ficam em locais totalmente diferentes dos scripts, o que as extensões permitem é acessar esses bancos (remotamente ou localmente), são "APIs"

Comment: E como eu faço isso? Pois aparentemente estou alterando o php.ini mas não surge efeito, mesmo eu reniciando o serviço apache2. Existe outra forma de desabilitar modulos?

Comment: @Reginaldev ai é muito especifico, porque se editou o php.ini correto do apache e reiniciou o apache com o comando correto então deveria funcionar, mas não tem como eu saber o que vc esta usando ... porque existem muitas distros linux (provavelmente muito mais) com diferentes formas de trabalhar, existem meios alternativos aos repositórios para usar PHP, por exemplo você pode ter usado o Xampp ao invés de usar o repositório. Não existe padrão para isso, por isso não tem como eu saber como é o seu ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Recomendo que faça uma pergunta detalhada nova.

Comment: Na verdade, se tiver instalado via repositório (como em Debian com apt-get) recomendo perguntar no site https://serverfault.com @Reginaldev

Comment: @Reginaldev ps: conferi os detalhes do PHPIniDir e acho q em questão de virtualhost isso não funciona, depois confirmo, mas é quase certo que só é possivel ter um php.ini no apache2handler, no fastcgi eu não tenho certeza, mas de qualquer forma isso é outra coisa, que não tem haver com o CLI. Talvez depois eu faça uma resposta dedicada ao fastcgi e ao apache2handler sobre o php.ini.